# How to make Folium's Heatmap weights not be influenced by the number of points in a region?

Tags: leaflet, heatmap, folium

I'm trying to build a home value Heat Map for a city using Folium (a python library that uses Leaflet to plot geo data). My Dataframe contains Latitude, Longitude, and Price (variable which is going to act as weight). Cheap areas should be green and expensive, red. The problem is that some poor regions with many dots seem to be more expensive, because those dots overlay each other and turn that region red. The method has some parameters to switch, but any of them solved my problem. Does anyone have a way to overcome this or an alternative library to make interactive heat maps using python?

Comment: Same problem here. What you want to see on the map is the average of each cluster instead of a value aggregation. Kibana can do that, but it's a database + dahsboard solution, not a python library. It's open source, btw.

Comment: Same problem here, too.

Comment: Same problem.. did anyone find a solution?

Comment: Not yet. After some months I’m trying the same thing and no solutions.

Comment: I came across the same problem. Any solutions yet?

Comment: Looking for solution to this as well. I'm really surprised folium not capable of this. I did find this example though. so I may try to implement this [way](https://github.com/jeffkaufman/apartment_prices). But i don't understand the point of the weight column then for the heatmap plugin, if it's purely based on single points overlap. 2 points overlapping with values of 1,2; show same "heat" as 2 points overlapping with values of 99,100. Shouldn't the 99, 100 over lap be "hotter" than 1,2?